# Returning NULL vs returning an obj with no data

Tags: c++, api

This is a rather a general API design question instead of C++ related question, anyways, what is generally accepted from functions that are expected to return an instance of an class: return NULL if something went wrong or return an instance of that class with no data?

This is my actual code: https://github.com/alexandernst/cpp-bitstring/blob/76030321b3a424236c3380067a0dc4f132fb8369/src/Bits.cpp#L360

Comment: Back in the day returning NULL was preferred because it avoids having to copy a big object. However, these days with C++11 and RVO there is really no point in doing that anymore so I'd say return an empty instance/ throw an exception. Also, used naked `new`'s is generally a bad idea especially if you have acess to smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would return NULL or throw.  Code which fails needs to be understood early.

The alternative of returning a "broken" object requires each function understanding the object is broken and dealing with it.

The NULL/throw requires you handle an error for each construction, and is in your face, if it fails

Comment: You can't "return NULL" if the function returns an instance of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this question:

"What is the promise of my function, and therefore the expectation of its client?

If the function promises to return an object, throw an exception if it can't. An exception represents the inability to keep a promise.

e.g.:

```
T make_t(Arg arg);  // promises to make a T, should throw if it can't
```

If the function promises that it *might* return an object, then express that in the interface:

```
boost::optional<T> maybe_make_t(Arg arg);
```

In this case, we would not expect an exception if the object was not made, merely an empty `optional<T>`. Because we have returned an optional, the caller is obliged to check it before he uses the value (or suffer an exception). He is now protected against his own logic errors.

If you can avoid it, seek to avoid returning pointers always. They create logic headaches for your callers.

Maybe (for some reason) you want to avoid exceptions, but still safely report failures to keep a promise?

Here's one way:

```
boost::variant<T, std::string> make_t_or_reason_why_not(Arg arg);
```

Now you're forcing the caller to use a static visitor to handle your result (this is good! it forces him to cover all code paths).

The promise is that you *will* return something, and that it will *either* be a `T` or a `string` explaining why the `T` was not made.